# Two errors when trying to open firefox using selenium (Python); System cannot find the file specified; Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

path = input("enter filepath: ")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)
driver.get("htpps://google.com")
```

This is the part of my code seemingly causing the error, I have been able to find any answers online. The code used to work when using r"c:\users\ellio\desktop\main" however this has since stopped working too, only without the top error. I have added the folder containg geckodriver to path and added the geckodriver exe to the same file as my code, but nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Here are the errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ellio\Desktop\main\app.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Answer (score 0):

give a specific path of your driver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe') #give location of driver you download
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');   
time.sleep(5)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) 
driver.quit()
```